# Include links in Sphinx table without extra whitespace

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm trying to create a table of links using the simple table format in Sphinx, like the example below:

```
===================================  ======
Website                              Type                                           
===================================  ======
`Google <https://www.google.com>`__  Search
`Yahoo <https://www.yahoo.com>`__    Search
`CNN <https://www.cnn.com>`__        News  
===================================  ======
```

If I understand correctly, I have to stretch the header breaks to the width of the longest row in the table, including the links. However, when the table is rendered the website is rendered as a link, leading to a lot of empty whitespace in the Website column.

[image]

Is there a way to create a table where the column is only as wide as the longest rendered hyperlink?

Comment: You could add a CSS class to the table, then use that to define the relative widths of the table columns in percentages. I also wonder why you use double underscores when a single is sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the table in a [table](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table) directive with `:widths: auto` works for me (tested with Sphinx 4.2.0).

```
.. table::
   :align: left
   :widths: auto
   
   ================================== ======
   Website                            Type                                           
   ================================== ======
   `Google <https://www.google.com>`_ Search
   `Yahoo <https://www.yahoo.com>`_   Search
   `CNN <https://www.cnn.com>`_       News  
   ================================== ======
```

Comment: Since Docutils 0.18 (2021-10-26), "auto" is the default "widths" setting for HTML5.

Comment: Support for Docutils 0.18 was added in Sphinx 5.0.0: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/changes.html#id291